# $SL(6, \mathbb{C})$ is not solvable

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

> Prove that $SL(6, \mathbb{C})$ is not solvable

Generally I never proved that a group is *not* solvable...

I thought about showing it is isomorphic to other groups which are not solvable (such as $S_6$) but I couldn't find any way to do this...

Other way I thought is to prove that the elements of the composition series are not $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$, but I'm not sure how to show this as well as...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- A subgroup of a solvable group is itself solvable.
- You seem to know that $A_6$ is not solvable.
- The set $G$ of $6\times6$ matrices such that each row and column has five zeros and a single one is a subgroup of $GL_6$ (known as permutation matrices because when viewed as linear transformations of $\Bbb{C}^6$ they simply permute the coordinates). $G$ is actually isomorphic to $S_6$. Furthermore, the determinant of a permutation matrix is the sign of the underlying permutation ($+1$ for even permutation and $-1$ for odd).
- The intersection of $G$ and $SL_6$ is equal to $A_6$, so ____________

Comment: If $\sigma\in S_6$ is any permutation, then the matrix of the linear transformation $T_\sigma:(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_6)\mapsto (x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},x_{\sigma^{-1}(2)},\ldots,x_{\sigma^{-1}(6)})$ is in $G$. And $T_\sigma T_\delta=T_{\sigma\delta}$ for all $\sigma,\delta\in S_6$.

Comment: Could you elaborate about the part why $G$ is a subgroup of $GL6$, and why is it isomorphic to $S_6$? Also, the last part is - $SL_6$ contains $A_6$ which is not solvable, therefore $SL_6$ is not solvable?

Answer (score 6):

Compute its commutator group: it is itself. This is a *perfect* group.

*Add:* To prove the special linear group is perfect for $n>1$, it suffices you prove that the [elementary matrices generate it](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Elementary_matrices_generate_the_special_linear_group) and, second, [that the elementary matrices are commutators.](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Every_elementary_matrix_is_a_commutator_of_unimodular_matrices) This requires some hypothesis either on the parameter $n$ or on the field, so pay attention to this.

Comment: (I could add more detail, but try to think about it for a while. Your proof should work for $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb C)$ for $n>1$.)

Comment: I understand stand why proving it solves my problem - as a group is solvable if and only if it's commutator series gets to the trivial element. Showing that it is equals to itself means that it cannot be trivial. However, to show it I need to prove that every matrix $M \in SL(n, \mathbb{C})$ is $M=aba^{-1}b^{-1}=[a,b]$, where $a,b \in SL(n, \mathbb{C})$. Can I get a hint for that?

Comment: @ChikChak See [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=jEKFYutSGGYC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=commutator+subgroup+of+SL(n,C)+stackexchange&source=bl&ots=2H85vzpmqp&sig=hGHvXx13R8wFbB7CQ_auLT5m82k&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCzOiFsuPcAhUPL1AKHfJvDTAQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) for the commutator subgroup of $SL(n,\Bbb{C})$.

Comment: @ChikChak That (what you claim you need to show) is a common misconception about the commutator subgroup; the commutator subgroup of a group is the subgroup *generated by* the commutators, and you actually just need to show that M is a product of commutators.

Comment: @Karl Kronenfeld Still, I do not know how to do that